# Discrete time stochastic process and stopping time confusion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am fairly new to formal measure theory applied to probability. I'm looking currently at discrete time stochastic processes and stopping times. I'm getting rather confused with viewing these strictly as functions. In particular, I am considering the stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ where each $X_i$ is a function on a sample space of single outcomes $\Omega$. During the process, we can observe different $\omega_t \in \Omega$ at each time.

Looking at the definition of a stopping time, this is defined as a random variable $T: \Omega \to \mathbb{N}$ such that it $\{T \leq t\} \subset 
F_t$. My problem is, for example, that a some practical examples consider $T$ to be defined as say the time until we roll first roll three 6s in a row. But surely then, $T$ depends on multiple random variables and therefore multiple outcomes in $\Omega$ in the sense that in this scenario, I feel like $T:\Omega^3 \to N$.

Even in a more simple case of say $T = \inf\{n \in \mathbb{N} | X_n = 1 \}$ say, is the T depending on the process in time or do we take say $\omega_1$ from the first random variable and calculate $T(\omega_1)$ and then this becomes our realisation of the stopping time. Or does $T$ evolve over time or depend on a sequence as in the initial example I posed? Again, I feel like viewing $T$ as a function is somewhat confusing me here.

I feel like maybe I'm overthinking this and missing something trivially obvious. Apologies if this doesn't make any sense and thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Comment: Stopping times apply to the paths of the process, and the paths are $\omega \mapsto \{X_0(\omega),X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega),...\}$ (the omegas are the same for each path). So $\tau(\omega)$ maps $\Omega$ to $\{0,1,...\}$

Comment: So, in the example of flipping a head or a tail and getting a 1 or -1 respectively to define the random variable $X_t$, then is $\Omega = \{ H,T\}$ or sequences of heads and tails. If it's the former then each path would just be $-1,-1,-1, ...$ or $1,1,1,1,...$? I though we would get (randomly) a different $\omega$ i.e. head or tail at each time step. In the former case it just seems like one random outcome a head is thrown and the entire trajectory is determined. Is my understanding flawed here?

Comment: you may do a quick search on "sample space of infinite coin flipping". But I'm referring to the general case for abstract spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no unique choice of $\Omega$.

In the case of flipping a countably infinite number of coins, one choice of $\Omega$ is the [Cantor Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space), which is the set of infinite length binary strings $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. In the case of rolling dice, you can choose instead for example $\Omega = 6^{\mathbb{N}}$.

One outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ is then some infinite length string (e.g., $1452631\dots$). The random process then maps each one of these infinite length binary strings and a corresponding index to some number.

It should then be easy to understand the stopping time as a function from $\Omega \to \mathbb{N}$. Taking your example of $T$ being the time until we first roll three 6s in a row, you can imagine each $\omega$ corresponds to one path of the entire process $\{ X_t(\omega) \}_{t \geq 0}$, and then you find the time at which three 6s first happens.